# Simple subtraction that I can't figure out.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A bat and a ball cost £1.10 in total. The bat costs £1 more than the ball. How much does the ball cost?

The answer to this question is somehow 5p. How?!! Should it not be 10p?

Comment: £1 is not £1 more than 10p...

Comment: I the ball cost 10p, the bat would cost 1£ more, i.e. £1.10 and both items togetrhre would cost £1.20, not £1.10.

Comment: Searching "bat ball" brings up many duplicates. Apparently, this is a popular "riddle".

Comment: The difference of two costs is 1 and sum of two costs is 1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's call the cost of the ball $x$. The bat costs $1$ more than the ball so it is $x+1$. Together, they cost $1.1$ so:
$$x+(x+1)=1.1$$
$$2x+1=1.1$$
$$\therefore\:x=\frac{1.1-1}{2}=0.05$$
Which gives you the $5p$. Hope I helped.

**Note**: I've ignored $£$ & $p$ so they don't get in the way; assume that $£1=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. All the answers were great however, I found yours very informative.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Let $x$ be the price of the ball (in pence), so $100+x$ is the price of the bat (also in pence). Then:

$$x + (100+x) = 110$$

What is $x$?

Comment: -1 : Either make that $x + (100 + x) = 110$ or $x + (1+x)=1.1$. As it stands this is wrong. 

For the rest, please do not blindly upvote. 

@OP after the correction, I have now upvoted.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Edited, tnx. Btw, is was a small derp, the downvote was unnecesary, the comment is enough.

Comment: just to bring it to your attention. I changed it to an upvote, :)

Comment: @Sabyasachi well, you certainly got it! =D